# Access logging in Spring Security with Spring Boot OAuth2

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-oauth2

I'm using the Spring Boot OAuth2 (https://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/docs/oauth2.html), making my own authorization server.

I haven't found a way to provide a coherent access log for users that hit `/oauth/token`, I'm wanting both successful and unsuccessful events. I've tried a lot of things, but they don't fulfill my needs in some way.

- Standard Spring Security `AuthenticationSuccessHandler`, `AuthenticationFailureHandler`, `AuthenticationEventPublisher`, `AccessDeniedHandler`, or `AuthenticationEntryPoint`: These don't seem to happen at all.
- Application events

  - `AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundEvent`: This happens, but I don't get any information about the client. Not even the username/client id.
  - `ServletRequestHandledEvent`: Good stuff, I get all the things, but only fires on success.
  - Spring Boot `AuditApplicationEvent`: Only happens on failure and the user principle is "unknown". Not even the IP address is available.
- `OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler`: This never happens either. I've installed it with the `AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer`, so I'm not sure what's going on with that.

So is there not a way to log what happens? I would think that any security related framework would have something available.

Comment: Did you try enabling Debug log? Adding this to properties file logging.level.org.springframework.security.oauth2: DEBUG

Comment: Nothing interesting, just about the token endpoint being hit.

Comment: What are you after? I've seen all authentication/authorization related logs once enabling debug log.

Comment: Well, I'm wanting to know the client id and where the request came from. I seem to only get the IP when `ServletRequestHandledEvent` serves `/error`.